# Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop: is there a limit of maximum 8 Nvidia GPUs simoultaneously connected?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu, nvidia-geforce

I have sucessefully connected up to 8 GPU (NVidia 1060) to Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop edition but everytime I try to connect a 9th GPU it crashes (does not restart, Kernel crash, report, etc).

I did clean installation then installed open source NVidia driver following standard procedure (Software&Updates -> Additional Drivers -> Driver 384.90)

Then I power off and add GPUs. It works fine upt to 8 GPU. Everytime I try to add a 9th GPU it crashes. I have a motherboard with capacity to connect up to 19 GPU (Asus B250).

So the question is very simple (is a yes or no question): is there a limit of 8 GPU that can be connected simoultaneously to Linux Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop Edition?

Update: I have uninstalled Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop and installed Ubuntu 16.04 Server Edition on same hardware and all 12 NVIDIA GPUs are working well. All 12 GPU have been recognized and are working 100%. But the question remains valid: is it possible to connect more than 8 Nvidia GPU using Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop Edition?

Comment: When does it crashes? Do your power supply provides enough power?

Comment: It crashes after giving command power off in Desktop. After power off I connect the 9th GPU. Then Power on. After power on Ubuntu then does not go beyond text messages "reporting Kernel crash, etc, etc" then black screen, then I can see only cursor blinking, then I wait, wait, wait and nothing... Enough power? 1275W (6GPU) +1200W (3GPU) and GPUs not even started working...

Comment: It seems you know what you're doing with PSU...
Next things to try is bios update and another distro (should not say that there;)

Comment: 1275W + 1200W is because I have 12 GPU (6+6) to connect but it seems I cannot go beyond 8 (exactly same limit I have at Windows 10 Pro 64). Will try with 16.05 Desktop, then 17.10 Server then 16.04 Server. Will make fresh installation on each one. Will also try option to connect all 12 GPU before install fresh copy 17.10 Desktop. Thanks .

Comment: installed successfully the 12 Nvidia GPU on exactly same hardware using Ubuntu Server 16.04

Comment: Feel free to add your answer and then accept it!

Comment: I gave up using Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop because it did not allow me to connect more than 8 GPU Nvidia. By coincidence, or not, this is the same limit of Windows 10 Pro 64 (it is a well know fact that Windows 10 Pro 64 has a limit of 8 GPUs of same manufacturer such as Nvidia or AMD). So I moved on to Ubuntu Server 16.04 and it is working flawless for days now with 12 Nvidia GPUs working full 100% capacity. So regarding answering my question I guess we have to wait someone saying he manage to overcome this limit of 8 Nvidia GPUs on Ubuntu Desktop 17.10

Comment: You can still write in the answer that this is currently not working in 17.10 and working fine in 16.04. Did you test with the same nvidia drivers? Probably a good idea to fill a bug on https://launchpad.net

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu is your bottleneck here.  Your power supply and your system board are going to be the bottlenecks.  I've successfully seen 12+ GPU clusters built with an Ubuntu backend.  However, we're also not talking that many screens attached to it.  The power consumption of those boxes however were *massive* I think they needed a massive power supply for it (something insanely huge)

Answer (score 0):

I am using two 850 watt power supplies on a Z170-AR motherboard along with one of those 4 way PCI-E  splitters and a m2 to  PCI-E adapter to get 10 PCI-E sockets. I have 5 GPUs on each 850 watt supply, each GPU set to 90 watts each using "sudo nvidia-smi -pl 90" and I also had two problems going from 8 to 10 nvidia GPU.

First was a bad SATA power connector, on the SATA cable going to the GPU 9 and 10 riser, one of the wires to the last SATA socket has its insulation melted off, so I guess it wasn't properly crimped at the factory (caused the miner to give an error message about losing communication with the PCI bus after it started running, causing all the GPU fans to go to 100% and the miner crashing).

The second issue I had was the xserver was not starting once I went over 8, i solved this by choosing advanced at the boot menu going into recovery mode, picking root shell from the menu and then trying xinit which ended with a seg fault, so I tried running "nvidia-xconfig" to write out a default config with one gpu and one display. I then exited and hit resume from the recovery menu and the xserver started as normal, and then I opened a xterminal ran nvidia-smi and saw 10 cards and started the claymore miner on its merry way